# Understanding perspective transform matrix elements interpretation

Tags: analytic-geometry, geometric-transformation

I am representing 3D points (vectors) in the following way:

```
(* conversion from 3D point, represented by normal list of \
coordinates, to matrxi column, suitable for transforms *)
ToColumn[point_] := Transpose[{Append[point, 1]}];
```

[image]

```
(* conversion from matrix column, representing 3D point, to a list, \
representing the same point *)
ToPoint[column_] := Take[Transpose[column/column[[4, 1]]][[1]], 3];
```

[image]

I.e. forth element serves as the scale factor.

(Is this conventional representation and what is the name of it?)

I am representing perspective transform with the following matrix:

```
PerspectiveXYZ[{x_, y_, z_}] := {
   {1, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 1, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 1, 0},
   {x, y, z, 0}
   };
```

so that

[image]

My question is: what is the sense of transform elements `x`, `y` and `z`?

I drew a cube of 8 points and transformed it with various values of these variables:

[image]

And found, that `x` and `y` controls projection plane orientation, while `z` controls both the scale and distance from origin point, while `z=1` means projecting into some small region (1?), and that the smaller this value, the bigger is the scale, becoming infinite when `z=0`.

Is there any clear geometric interpretation of these values, especially `z`? May be they should be substituted with `1/z` or something for better interpretation?

May be my vector model should be changed?

Comment: It's a fact that if you use "homogeneous coordinates" then a perspective (or projective) transformation from a (projective) plane to a (projective) plane can be represented by a $3 \times 3$ "homogeneous" matrix.  This is one reason homogeneous coordinates are useful, though they seem unintuitive at first.

Comment: I am using 4x4 matrices.

Comment: But warpPerspective accepts a $3 \times 3$ matrix, so why are you using $4 \times 4$ matrices?  Also, I don't understand exactly what your question is.

Comment: See my update. 3x3 matrix gives the same result (I think) as 4x4 matrix with 3rd row/column excluded / turned to zero. My question is more general.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm confused now about why the $4 \times 4$ matrix isn't invertible, I had thought that it should be.  Btw, a decent reference for this stuff is the book Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision by Hartley and Zisserman.

Comment: I can use lower right element as `1` too. This is probably also perspective transform, but I can't understand it too.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Conventional definitions to perspective projection and other geometric transformations in homogeneous form are NOT flawless. You may have been confused by `space elation` and `perspective projection`. A projection should be singular and Not invertible indeed.

Comment: [QuickDraw GX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickDraw_GX) used $3\times3$ matrices for perspective mappings. There were a number of applications written using this perspective interface.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix

[image]

defines a perspective projection onto the plane with equation

$Ax + By + Cz + D=0$

Perspective is build with the center in the origin.